# USB star config

Tags: usb, switch, hub, master

I'm facing the following scenario: Step1: I have a board (device1) that has  a USB stick (device2) connected to it. Step2: I have to unplug the USB stick (device2) and connect the board (device1) to a workstation (device3) in order to execute commands, flash, etc.

- Step1: I need to connect USB_Device1 as master to USB_Device2 as slave.
- Step2: I need to connect USB_Device1 as slave to USB_Device3 as master.

Step1 and Step2 are sequential.
I tried using a USB switch box, but it does not work because slave and master physical position in the USB box cannot be reversed.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: It might be better to explain your use case. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm facing the following scenario:
Step1:  I have a board (device1) that has connected to it an USB stick (device2)
Step2: I have to unplug the USB stick (device2) and connect the board (device1) to a workstation (device3) in order to execute commands/flash/etc

Comment: @DobreanuNicolae Please don’t clarify in comments but rather edit your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

USB ports are either host-ports (master) or device-ports (slave).
They can't be BOTH at the same time. The USB standard simply doesn't support that.

So your device 1 needs to have at least 2 USB ports. 1 slave and 1 master port.
And then it is just a matter of connecting them in the right order.

But normally you will NOT be able to control device 2 from device 3. They will be on 2 different USB bus systems.
Only if device 1 contains software that emulates a USB hub it can appear to device 3 as if it is a hub to which device 2 is connected.

Comment: They are not hosts at the same time, there is a diagram attached to the question.

Comment: @DobreanuNicolae You will have to really clarify your setup and what you exactly want to achieve. Currently it is highly unclear. That diagram is pretty meaningless as it doesn't provide any more information than your written question.

Comment: 'm facing the following scenario: Step1: I have a board (device1) that has connected to it an USB stick (device2) Step2: I have to unplug the USB stick (device2) and connect the board (device1) to a workstation (device3) in order to execute commands/flash/etc